# Matlab Boxplot: Use a specific percentile as the upper whisker OR remove redundant outliers after manual upper whisker edit

Tags: matlab, plot, boxplot

For boxplots in MATLAB, I'd like to ask if a specific percentile can be used as the upper whisker. I'd like to use the 95th percentile as the upper whisker and 5th percentile as the lower whisker.

MATLAB's default behaviour is to have the whisker length = 1.5 * IQR (75th percentile - 25th percentile) and this whisker length can be changed to another multiple of IQR, but not to a specific percentile. Please can the method to change this be explained.

For example, for the following 100 pieces of data:

50 (repeated 80 times),
76 (repeated 10 times),
91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100

or in MATLAB:

```
A([1:80],1) = 50; A([81:90],1) = 76; A([91:100],1) = [91:100]; boxplot(A)
```

Is there a way to specify 95 or even 76 to be within the whiskers? or the value of the upper whisker?

I have adjusted the upper and lower whiskers (although lower whisker is not needed in this example) using the following code; however this code doesn't remove outliers within the whisker making the result look unclear.

```
p([1:2],1) =prctile(A,[5,95])
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Upper Whisker'));
for j=1:length(h);
ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
ydata(2) = p(2,j);
set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end
% Replace all y values of adjacent value
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Upper Adjacent Value'));
for j=1:length(h);
ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
ydata(:) = p(2,j);
set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end
% Replace lower end y value of whisker
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Lower Whisker'));
for j=1:length(h);
ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
ydata(1) = p(1,j);
set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end
% Replace all y values of adjacent value
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Lower Adjacent Value'));
for j=1:length(h);
ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
ydata(:) = p(1,j);
set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following:

```
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Outliers'));
for j=1:length(h);
  ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
  xdata = get(h(j),'XData');
  remdata = (ydata >= p(1,j)) & (ydata <= p(2,j));
  ydata(remdata) = [];
  xdata(remdata) = [];
  set(h(j),'XData',xdata,'YData',ydata);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried for a while to understand "standard" or "default" boxplots in Matlab, and more specifically, what the whisker length is.

Of course, the manual gives a totally useless, recursive definition when it states that "whiskers are drawn from the ends of the interquartile ranges to the furthest observations within the whisker length"

I think you are incorrect, though, when stating that "MATLAB has a whisker length of 1.5 IQR". What it does by default is finding all sample data that are below (Q25 - 1.5 IQR) and above (Q75 + 1.5 IQR), and calling those data "outliers". THEN, the upper whisker is the largest value in the sample that is not an upper outlier, and the lower whisker is the smallest sample value that is not a lower outlier.

In other words, the total distance between whiskers is not fixed and equal to 4 IQR, but is the distance between the largest and the smallest value in the sample that are not outliers.