# Change inter quartile range(IQR) for boxchart

Tags: matlab, boxplot, iqr

I had to use only [boxchart](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boxchart.html) for my application where I need to change Inter Quartile Range(IQR) from default range i.e. 25% for the lower and 75% is the upper quartiles respectly. I see changing of IQR in [boxplot](https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html) using the Outliers Tag box object possible, but for [boxchart](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boxchart.html) there is no much help found in different forums.

As from the help of boxchart, it is using [quantile Algorithms](https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantile.html#btf91zm) where the upper quartile corresponds to the 0.75 quantile and the lower quartile corresponds to the 0.25 quantile default, I have statistics and machine learning toolbox,
my problem is similar to this [Matlab Boxplot: Use a specific percentile as the upper whisker OR remove redundant outliers after manual upper whisker edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962191/matlab-boxplot-use-a-specific-percentile-as-the-upper-whisker-or-remove-redunda) but with the [boxchart](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boxchart.html).
Can I get any help?

Answer (score 0):

As per the reply of service request to Mathworks, there is no feature available in the boxchart function to allow for adjusting percentile limits(IQR) till current i.e. R2021b release.

Hope this feature may available in the the future release.